# A relative and linear layout placing issue

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-linearlayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.3"
    >
</LinearLayout> 



<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout1"
    >
</LinearLayout>    


 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="0.35"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout2"
    >
</LinearLayout>
```

i am trying to align the codes here in a row. it being the relative layout as the parent and 3 linear layout as the child. My java codes would generate text view and 2 edit text as the child of the linear layout and display it in a row. however, it turned out vertical stacking on top of each other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each `LinearLayout` you should set the `android:orientation` attribute as `horizontal`. See the code below:

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Currently, your orientation is set to `vertical` so it is stacking on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Set the LinearLayout orientation attribute from    **Vertical** to    **Horizontal** if u want it's child in a row.

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

I hope this is the answer that you want..